# Transform C# List<KeyValuePair<int,string> to TypeScript Object that can be used in Angular 8 DropDownList using ngFor

Tags: angular, .net-core, drop-down-menu, ngfor, keyvaluepair

I have a simple list of KeyValuePair that is being created in MVC Controller and passed to an Angular component.ts. Within Angular I can manually create a key value pair to use in dropdown list as:

```
object: { [key: number]: string } = { 2: 'foo', 1: 'bar' };
```

This is what I have in the component.html:

```
 <option *ngFor="let program of object | keyvalue " value={{program.key}}>{{program.value}}</option>
```

With this method, I get exactly what I expect -- a drop down list. If I use the KeyValyePair that I received from MVC controller the drop down list displays [ object Object] instead of the value I am looking for. 
So my question is, how to I transform my KeyValuePair list into the { [key: number], string} format the TypeScript uses?

This is my first attempt at using Angular in DotNet Core 3.1 MVC App and unfortunately at this point I have only a basic knowledge of TypeScript.

Answer (score 1):

object: {[key: number]: string}[];

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let program of object">
  <option [value]="program.key|keyvalue">{{program.value | keyvalue}}</option>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution offered by Askash did not work 100% in my case but it lead me to the right answer. When I return the KeyValuePair from MVC to the component.ts I ended  up with an array of KeyValuePair that looked like Key: 1 Value: "Whatever".

I used the code from Askash with slight changes and it worked

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let program of object">
  <option [value]="program.Key">{{program.Value}}</option>
</ng-container>
```

I did not need the two keyvalue pipes and program.key changed to program.Key and the same with value -- value became Value as reflected by the KeyValuePair object.

The key for me was wrapping the `<option></option>` in a ng-container.

Thanks